# Upload file in MAC using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, file-upload, applescript, robotframework

I am trying to upload file in MAC using selenium java. The button does not have input tag. So i tried using robot script and with apple script but could not proceed. Can any one help me.

Apple script

```
    tell application "System Events"
    --one second delay
    delay 1
    --To press command+shift+G
    keystroke "G" using {command down, shift down}
    delay 2
    --Enter file path
    keystroke "file path"
    
    keystroke return
    delay 1
    keystroke return
    
end tell
```

Java code :

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runtime.exec(filePath);
```

And also please let me know how to pass filePath from java into apple script?

Answer (score 0):

After trying several methods, below codes worked without any issue for me on the MAC. I added "Command + W" keys.

```
//Click on the Choose file Button
browser.findElement(By.className("choosefile")).click();
//Path of file need to be upload
File file = new File("/Users/John/Desktop/IMG_0100.PNG");
StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(file.getAbsolutePath());
//Copy to clipboard 
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection, null);
try {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_W);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_G);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_G);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);

    // Paste the clipBoard content - Command ⌘ + V.
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);

    // Press Enter (GO - To bring up the file.)
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.delay(1000 * 4);

    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

} catch (AWTException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```